# Is a Chi Squared Test appropriate if values are summaries of dependent trials?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a control group and a test group. In the test group people are called twice as often as in the control group. The other variable is if the customer said "yes" or "no" to a question. If the customer said "yes" at least once the variable is summarized as 1 otherwise 0.

So I have the possible combinations (control, 0), (control, 1), (test, 0), (test, 1). In the end I have one observation per customer, however every value for each customer is from repeated observations. Is a Chi Squared Test appropriate in this scenario?

Comment: You have questioned the test group and the control group in different ways.  Why?  I would have thought this is not comparing the same thing in the two groups.  Do you have the answers to the first call in the test group which you could compare to the single call in the control group?